# Recursive makefile for compiling my own library

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have an application directory with source code and within that same directory there is another directory with a library. I want to compile this using recursion. Here is the example:

I make a fictitious directory tree as:

```
> mkdir lib
> touch lib/src1.c
> touch lib/src2.c
```

Then in the main directory I create a main.c with the code

```
int main(){return 0;}
```

and a makefile with

```
all: test

main.o: lib/libsomelib.a
lib/libsomelib.a: lib

lib:
    make --directory=$@
.PHONY: lib

test: main.o
    cc -L./lib -lsomelib main.o -o $@
```

within lib I create a makefile with:

```
all: libsomelib.a
.PHONY: all

libsomelib.a: src1.o src2.o
    ar rcs $@ $^
```

Running make from the parent directory has the desired effect.

Now, if I remove say lib/src1.o:

```
rm lib/src1.o
```

and run make again, the makefile will run recursively into lib but since the dependency for the library is checked BEFORE the library is rebuilt, the main application is not updated.

I need to RERUN make to compile the executable.

How do I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a drawback of using Make recursively: it has trouble handling dependencies correctly. Would you prefer to put the library's dependency information in the main makefile, or sometimes rebuild the executable when there's nor real reason to?

Comment: Beta, thank you. Probably the common procedure would be to compile my library and app separately. However, since I am in the stage of developing both this kind of makefele would be useful (not to mention that I would like to learn how to fix this kind of problems).

Comment: *Would you prefer to put the library's dependency information in the main makefile, or sometimes rebuild the executable when there's no real reason to?*

Answer (score 0):

Simply change:

```
lib:
    make --directory=$@
.PHONY: lib

test: main.o
    cc -L./lib -lsomelib main.o -o $@
```

to:

```
lib/libsomelib.a:
    make --directory=$@

test: main.o lib/libsomelib.a
    cc -L./lib -lsomelib main.o -o $@
```

Note that, as Beta intimated, [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/), as it gets you thinking on a per-directory basis, rather than across the entire tree, cutting you off from the real power of make. If you get into the habit of writing heirarchical make files, you'll find that your build are not only faster, but more reliable (less need to 'make clean && make').